# How to read a specific prefix information from gs1 barcode, with scanner?

Tags: barcode, hardware, barcode-scanner, gs1-ai-syntax

I am working with products that contains gs1 barcodes where are  many application identrifiers (AI) or prefix, like (01)....(17).....(10).... . The scanner I 've got its called honeywell ms5145 and when I scann the barcode it prints as output the numbers of (01) identifier and ends before the AI (17). After a bit of searching I found some configuration barcodes where one of them is for usb full speed. When I scan this config and after that the barcode of the product the output was defferent and it was printing all the information of the barcode from (01) to (10). The (10) application identifier is for batch lot numbers and thats I want to scan. For example lets say that the barcode in one product is (01)98923424(17)99933333(10)111111B. If I scan without the usb full speed config the output will be 98923424 which is the contex of the (10) application identifier and if I scan with the config of usb full speed the output will be 9892342499933333111111B,without of course the AI.**My question** is, is there any  way without any software configuration to extract only the batch lot number of the gs1 barcode. Genneraly is it possible to extract what ever application identifier I want with one scan ?

Comment: This document contains specifications. [GS1 General Specifications](https://www.gs1.org/docs/barcodes/GS1_General_Specifications.pdf) For example, the flow chart on page 488 may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that valid GS1 codes *must* contain `01` identifier, and must *not* repeat same identifier.

If you have a GS1 structured code like `(01)12345678901238(17)231220(10)987654` you most likely scan everything.

But, your scanner can be configured to manipulate the data using the [MetroSet2](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/What-is-MetroSet2-and-where-can-it-be-downloaded) software.  Look at data formatting.

I have not tried it since I do not have said scanner, but typically formatting is some variant of substring. This will work if the barcodes your work with have same length. GS1 structures *may* switch order though, this will cause your substring to be incorrect.

An alternative could be scanners that are programmable in Javascript such as those from [Code Corporation](https://codecorp.com/products/scanflex-js) **I am not affiliated with CodeCorp in any way, but work with barcodes)**